# Disable "manual" scrolling and only use scrollTo in scrollView

Tags: appcelerator

I am developing an iOS app in Appcelerator and in this I am trying to make navigation based on vertical and horizontal scrolling.

I am using scrollable views for horizontal scrolling and a normal scrollview for vertical scrolling.

What I am trying to do is that the user cannot manually swipe up and down to scroll but need to click on a button that does a scrollTo movement. How can I disable "manual" scrolling and only use the up and down buttons? I think I need to do this to be able to have a table too.

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about scrollTo however if you set scrollEnabled to false on your scroll view, it will prevent manual scrolling. Then, if the content size is bigger than the scroll view, you can use setContentOffset:Animated: to scroll the view.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**SwiftUI**
Use  `.scrollDisabled(true)`

```
 ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                   // Some content
            }
            .scrollDisabled(true)
}
```